# false response format by using back or reload buttons in IE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, internet-explorer, responseformat

recently i encountert a problem in IE and other browser, which i also noticed on railscasts.com some time ago.

For example, loading the page:

- railscasts.com/episodes/some_id#comments

would load a  railscasts episode with the comment tab activated. navigating to the "similar" tab would change the url to:

- railscasts.com/episodes/some_id#similar

if i would click on the back or (IE) reload button, i would see the json representation for the comments.

Digging in the log file i found this:

Chrome:

- EpisodesController#show as HTML
- EpisodesController#show as HTML

IE

- EpisodesController#show as HTML
- EpisodesController#show as */*

in an related stackoverflow question it was suggested to change the order `respond_to` block and make the first respond block 'html'

```
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json
end
```

meaning, if no respond format is given it would take the first one to respond with. not a DRY solution for the problem. also not possebly if you are using `respond_with(@episodes)`

another solution is to set the default response format in the routes.rb:

```
match 'episodes/:id' => 'episodes#show', :defaults => { :format => 'html' }
```

which is also not DRY because you dont want to write that for every route you define.

Lastly i found a suggestion to use a before_filter in the application controller:

```
before_filter :set_default_response_format
protected
def set_default_response_format
  request.format  = "html" if request.format == "*/*" && request.content_type.nil?
end
```

which seems a stable solution for that problem.

It seems weird that not more programmer encounter that problem, or am i doing sth. wrong in the first place ?

Comment: I encountered the same issue and solved it with a before filter

Comment: I encountered the same issue - before filter seems a decent option right now, but maybe it should be a rails issue or the task of some middleware...